# .NET Core migrating API from 2.2 to 3.1 DateTimeOffset problem

Tags: .net-core, migrate, datetimeoffset

I host an .NET Core API that used to be in 2.2 and I've migrated to 3.1. I have several models that use DateTimeOffset, and in both API versions (2.2 and 3.1) they accept a value like "2021-06-16T15:32:57-03:00".

However, a client is sending in the format "2021-06-16T15:32:57-0300"  (without the colon after the last "3" - so 0300 rather than 03:00.  The client's format now raises a ModelState.IsValid error. This used to work in 2.2.

Unfortunately the offset dates are used in many places and models. Is there an easy way for me to tell the API to accept the 0300 type of format instead?

Answer (score 0):

The [source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ca3c11d64516217134430d04354ac770b07c91ef/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Globalization/DateTimeParse.cs#L11) doesn't seem to have changed at all, and still appears to handle +0800 as well as +08:00 (around lines 525)